# Nodejs, how to pass parameters to Javascript in PUG/jade views

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, pug

I want to pass a variable when rendering my view and use this variable in client side Javascript. I already got partially, but it's rendering wrong. I use PUG view (or Jade).

Example:

**Server Side**

```
res.render('xyzView', { xyzVal: 'my_values_xyz'});
```

**Client Side**: PUG view

```
extends ../layout
block content
    script(type='text/javascript')
        var getVal= #{xyzVal};
```

It's creating a tag `<var></var>` on output instead `var` only, like this:

```
//- other HTML tags and codes
//-..
//-..
<script type="text/javascript">
    <var>getVal = 'my_values_xyz'</var>   /// <<<<<====== THE PROBLEM IT'S HERE
</script>
```

The right way should be:

```
//- other HTML tags and codes
//-..
//-..
<script type="text/javascript">
    var getVal = 'my_values_xyz';
</script>
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add [plain text](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html)

```
extends ../layout
block content
    script(type='text/javascript')
        | var getVal= #{xyzVal};
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a '.' after script like this:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    var getVal= #{xyzVal};
```

Comment: Unbelievable .... I read and reread the documentation and could not see the use of the "." and the "|". Both work! Thank you guys!